# Why does a "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date_time'" error come up for my first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe that starts with the date_time column and is followed by multiple variables like below.

[image]

However, when I try to graph time vs. variable, I get the "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date_time'" error.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20,8))    
ax[0].plot(df.date_time, df.P1_VWC)
ax[1].plot(df.date_time, df.P2_VWC)
```

Any ideas why my first column is being ignored?

Thanks for your time,
-Bojan

Comment: date_time is your df's index, not a column. to plot against the index, `ax[0].plot(df.P1_VWC)` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your `date_time` is not a column rather than it is the index of the dataframe. To move back to as a column, you can reset the index of the dataframe by using this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Otherwise, you can also use the index directly as MrFuppes suggested in the comment.